# Monitoring another server status by python?best way is to telnet or using socket?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I want to check the status of server(up or down) as well as apache,mysql running or not and CPU , memory usage. For this measurement can I use telnet.best to implement this or any library?? Ubuntu is my server.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to do this over the Internet you should use ssh not telnet. In Python ssh2 protocol is implemented in [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/). But you may also want to take a look to [ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com/) or [salt](http://www.saltstack.com/).